# Execution times of a stored procedure are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have a stored procedure and several statements in it. The below is execution time statistics of the procedure:

> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
>   0 ms. SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed
>   time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 11484 ms,  elapsed time =
>   2277 ms.
>
> (29 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 11484 ms,  elapsed time =
>   2283 ms.

As you can see the total of 4562 ms. But when I look at the status bar I see that it took 2 seconds. I expect that it should be 4 seconds. Why are these two different?

[image]

Comment: Say, 12000ms, that's 12s, divided over 6 cpu's that' 2s. That's just a wild guess I'm taking.

Comment: based on the info shared it looks like the first one is the execution time of one of the statement in the procedure and the last one is total execution time of the procedure. it is the sum of all the statements within the procedure

Answer (score 1):

the first wait of 2277 ms is the execution time of a statement within the procedure. the second one 2283 ms is the complete duration of the procedure. so the procedure ran in 2283 ms and not in (2277  + 2283) ms

So If I create a procedure with a wait for 2 seconds like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_delay AS BEGIN
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
END
GO

SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO

EXEC usp_delay;
```

You can see the statistics io and time as below:

> SQL Server parse and compile time: 
>      CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server parse and compile time: 
>      CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 9 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>      CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2000 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>      CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2010 ms.

Notice that it has 2 elapsed time >= 2000ms one for the statement `WAITFOR DELAY` and one for the complete procedure time. this is what you are seeing as well and the procedure runs in 2010 ms and not 4010 ms based on the above sum.